# Badge on top of right navigation button

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, badge, uibuttonbaritem

I have a requirement where I need to show the badge number on top of the right navigation button. Something like this:

[image]

How to show the badge on top of `UIBarButtonItem` in the navigation bar?

I am still using Xcode 7.3.1, Swift 2.2.

Comment: Simply user interface  drag imageview and set image and then set label on top right position and then  change layer of label to make it circular , and then set number on it , simple

Comment: It needs to be in the navigation bar - the badge on top right of right UIBarButtonItem. So I cant simply do it.

Comment: why not ! under navigationbar , drag bar item and then drag imageview and label inside it , did u try this

Comment: under navigationbar , drag bar item - I did till that. But later I am not able to drag a imageview and a label inside it. I have tried it but its not working.

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari U need to learn something. Drag image on navigation bar button wont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working with this Framework here:

https://github.com/enmiller/ENMBadgedBarButtonItem-Swift

Otherwise you could create your own View with a Badge. Just make an Custom UINavigationItem.

For example:

```
let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: AnyOfYourCustomViews)
```

Comment: I am still not using XCode 8.0. I am using XCode 7.3.1. Is an older version of the code available?

Comment: Of Course. Check out here: https://github.com/enmiller/ENMBadgedBarButtonItem-Swift/releases

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try and see if this works. Else I will get back here :)